# Find command starting point with path pruning

Tags: find, directory

I am always running into this problem without learning.

When searching for a file with the starting point in another directory I give the full path to the starting point and it does not work. Same happens when I am in the starting directory and give the full path to the starting point.

```
find /path/from/start/. -path './anaconda3/*' -prune -o -name '*R' -print
```

goes straight to the "pruned" directory like there was candy in it.

If I'm at the starting point, starting from `.` works fine. Otherwise `find` does not prune the path I'm trying to escape.

```
find . -path './anaconda3/*' -prune -o -name '*R' -print
```

works.

Maybe a detailed answer will settle this problem, sometimes I learn but the next time I face the `find` command I run into the same problem like I have never done this before. The `-path pattern` chapter of the man page is trying to say something but I think it is in vogon and I do not possess a babel fish.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`-path` matches against the full pathname generated by `find`. When you start from `.`, the pathname starts with that; when you start from `/path/from/start` (the `/.` isn’t necessary and will only complicate matters), the pathname starts with `/path/from/start`.

So you need to match against the full path.

```
find /path/from/start -path '/path/from/start/anaconda3/*' -prune -o -name '*R' -print
```

Since this will prune `/path/from/start/anaconda3` itself, you don’t even need the `/*` part at the end:

```
find /path/from/start -path /path/from/start/anaconda3 -prune -o -name '*R' -print
```

Basically, with `-path` you need to remember that the start path is repeated in the “criteria” paths:

```
find /path/from/start -path /path/from/start/anaconda3 -prune -o -name '*R' -print
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

find . -path './anaconda3/*' -prune -o -name '*R' -print
     ^        ^
```

If that’s the only `anaconda3` directory you want to prune, or if you want to prune all `anaconda3` directories, you can use `-name` instead:

```
find /path/from/start -name anaconda3 -prune -o -name '*R' -print
```

All this also applies when you specify multiple start paths: each `-path` expression will match against the full pathname produced from any of the start paths. So you could have the following:

```
find /path/from/start /otherpath/from/elsewhere \
     -path /path/from/start/anaconda3 -prune -o \
     -path /otherpath/from/elsewhere/anaconda3 -prune -o \
     -name '*R' -print
```

Comment: Also you could have multiple starting points... `find ./foo ./bar -path ./foo/test` would not match `./bar/test`. The `-printf` action of GNU find has the format directives `%H` and `%P` for the starting point corresponding to the file and the path under the starting point. But I don't think there's a similar condition to go between `-path` and `-name`.

Comment: Indeed, it’s worth describing multiple start path handling; I’ve added that. I considered mentioning `%H` and `%P` but thought that would just end up confusing since they can’t be used to match :-/.

Comment: Removing `.`s and including full path to path did the trick. I thought flaunting dots was good practice in linux, that is what the "cool linux kids" do.

Comment: @AWE flaunting dots can be useful in some circumstances, *e.g.* with `mv` to avoid moving multiple files to a single file instead of a directory; but with `find` it’s not.